# Laravel 7 - Use Middleware and except in route file

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 7 for an API project, I have created a JWT Middleware, and I want to apply it to all my routes, except 2 of them.

For now I have in my `routes/api.php` :

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('ping', 'Api\Ping\PingController@ping');

    // auth routes
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'login/'], function () {
        Route::post('login', 'Api\Auth\AuthController@login');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt:api'], function() {
           Route::get('me', 'Api\Auth\AuthController@me');
           Route::post('refreshToken', 'Api\Auth\AuthController@refresh');
           Route::post('logout', 'Api\Auth\AuthController@logout');
        });
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt:api'], function() {
        Route::resource('users', 'Api\User\UserController');
        // my other routes protected .....
```

I don't like this approach because I need to copy the middleware.

I tried this approach :

```
Route::group(
    [
        'middleware' => ['jwt:api', ['except' => 'login/login']],
        'prefix' => 'v1/',
    ], function() {
```

But I have this error :

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Is it possible ? I want to group everything in my route file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. You can pass additional [parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#middleware-parameters) to middleware via dots and check in middleware to do not use passed routes
2. Also, you can overwrite middleware and add some property\constant with array of excepts, like in csrf middleware
3. Implement ability in Laravel core to pass except array as in your exmaple and make a PR to framework github
4. Left it as you have done

Comment: I thought Except array was working, since it works in Controller. I guess I will let as I did, I don't want to define exceptions / routes in other files. Laravel is a little messy

Comment: A lot of features and flexibility produce a lot of mess)